# Please reopen this question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-closed

It is my opinion that this question is perfectly valid: [Pure high-bit multiplication in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478253/is-there-a-pure-high-bit-multiplication-library)

I don't see why it is closed. I don't know the appropriate wrapper for SSE instructions for 16 bit fixed point, and I got a quick good answer which I accepted.

Comment: Your other question was already discussed by the community and I think it's pretty clear what was decided in [What's up with this question being “debate” closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131595/1288)  If you want *this* post to be seriously considered, maybe you should try to stay on point.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: One has nothing to do with the other, but, judging by the reactions to my questons, your community is totally disfunctional.

Comment: If one has nothing to do with the other, then why did you bring it up?

Comment: *"judging by the reactions to my questons, your community is totally disfunctional"* Now that tempts me to change my tune, Ron. The ban on make-a-list questions is there for good reason. My argument below is based on the assumption that the expectation for the occupation of the category in on order of 1.

Comment: @RonMaimon, I'm on your side here, but calling SO disfunctional isn't going to help the case.

Comment: @RonMaimon: please stop being an arse. You've made your case, your question is re-open. The mod who originally closed it re-opened it along with other members, and _actually took the time to make it fit better on SO_, even if that's just a few words and getting rid of a useless meta-tag. Leave it.

Comment: @RonMaimon - Sometimes, all it takes is changing some wording in the question and then -- respectfully -- making your case to have your question reopened. The people that volunteer their time here are simply trying to keep this site great by filtering out noise, and there is no need to be disrespectful or insulting.

Comment: @Mat: I will not stop being an arse until I see that being an arse isn't sanctioned. This is the physicists' 11th commandment.

Answer (score 31):

Asking a question which states **"are there any libraries that..."** implies either you're looking for *yes or no* (which is stupid), or you are looking for the name and/or link to this library.

Questions which request links are routinely closed as not constructive.  I closed yours as not constructive.  I explained why.  I, and a couple other users, edited your question to remove the reek of link rot, and reopened it.  See, we're not all nazi klansmen - I took the time to clean up your question and reopen it.

You reverted the edit, so your question will now remain closed.

Comment: Um, you locked it in the state that doesn't have “are there any libraries that”.

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, I did.

Comment: I liked the old angry version of this post.

Comment: @shep i did too, but guess what!

Comment: Just got a downvote on this answer, which brought it back to my attention.  Aaah, good times.  This answer still sounds angry, but without the context. If you're interested, read the original https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/131723/1 and check out OP's account--suspended *network wide* until '26.  That's a suspension applied by an employee, not a moderator from any one site. Too bad most of the questions he's asked here have been nuked, or you could go visit why he "got the hook."

Answer (score 11):

I'm rather on Ron's side here.

I would argue that *"Is there a [something rare and hard to find with google]?"* is enough different from *"What's a good book on [hot topic of the month that you can hardly avoid without going to live in a cave]?"* to be considered for different treatment.

My guilty secret: [Is there a “File IO in Postscript for Dummies”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5136164/2509)

Comment: Still, there is no need to insult the entire community by being insulting without fully understanding how or why we make the decisions we do. The op could have approached this a lot more responsibly. With that being said, I can't disagree with what you've said. Sometimes there are long tail questions; however, those are the toughest to make decisions on without knowledge of the subject or starting to doubt every decision you make. +1 for making a good case.

Comment: @jmort253: There is obviously a need to insult the entire communitee, because you are _a communitee_, and communitees need to take insults, otherwise they oppress by their nature.

Answer (score 9):

In the OP's opinion, their question is *always* perfectly valid.

Will has stated that if you rephrase the question it can then be flagged for reopening - you haven't made that edit yet. You need to phrase it in such a way that it isn't a *"Is there x out there?"* type question, and more of a *"How do I do xyz [using abc]?"* type question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this point: why would the question be more useful if it were rephrased? Sometimes, as pointed out by dmckee, things are just hard to find, and we want to know if they exist.

Comment: An edit of this variety would obviously allow us to duck the whole issue.

Comment: What edit? I don't know what I'm supposed to rephrase. The question is very terse and very clear.

Answer (score 9):

While there may be some debate as to whether Ron included "What he tried", I don't necessarily feel that a question should be judged on the merit of only one metric or criteria.  Is it possible that some questions are complex enough to not justify this requirement?

One of the other criteria we use to measure a question's value on StackOverflow is to ask if it's a question that could be solved with a quick Google Search.

There are countless examples of one-liner questions on the site where a quick Google search can find the answer, even if it's not a topic that you as an answerer are familiar with. There are closed questions on SO with a comment in the question posted by me that says "here's the link", yet as the commenter, I knew very little to nothing of the subject.

This question, on the other hand, is one where I'm not even sure where to start in terms of Googling the answer. Should we not make room on the site for questions where the subject matter is more advanced? This isn't one of those "My code threw an error and I'm not going to tell you the error because I don't know what a debugger is" type questions; instead, this appears to be a question on a topic that's much more advanced, asked by someone legitimately trying to understand more about it.

Perhaps I'm just particularly ignorant when it comes to this topic, but perhaps this is one we should rethink.