# When I make a meta proposal, should I post an answer that simply agrees with the question?

Tags: discussion, meta

Some of my meta proposals seem to have a lot of support, meaning they get a lot of up-votes, however none of the answers posted agree with the question

In these cases, should I make an answer that just agrees with the question?

**Edit:** I think what I'm really trying to ask is:

Does the users that decide the fate of such proposals take question votes into account when they decide if they should implement something or not? Or do they only look at answers?

Two examples are [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132833/158605), which has two answers that I don't really like at 1-2 upvotes, but the question votes are at 9, or [this one](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2948/1130), which had many up-votes but users tell me nothing got done because all the answers posted disagreed with the proposal (I did post my own answer agreeing with the proposal a month or two later)

Comment: Now I'm waiting for your "Yes, you should" answer...

Comment: I'm going to get rich by selling "The one secret of how to increase your MSO rep by 200%" and just recommending this. Now then, I'm off to design some unbelievably irritating banner ads that you will see wherever you go on the Internet for a year.

Comment: @Bart :) The question is only some proposals, not all. The proposal that prompted this question is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132833/158605), where so far I don't like either answer given, although another one I had in mind was [this one](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/2948/1130) where users told me nothing was done because all the answers disagreed with the proposal despite the many upvotes it had (I did finally post an answer agreeing with the question a month or two later)

Comment: @PopularDemand That's why I'm asking instead of simply posting an answer agreeing with my proposals :) I'm not sure if such a thing is OK or not

Comment: Do you think it might help if you had the [feature-request] tag on the questions?

Comment: recommended reading for implementation-vs-voting questions: [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html) "Community feedback is great, but it should never be used as a crutch, a substitute for thinking deeply about what you're building and _why_. Always try to identify what the underlying needs are, and come up with a sensible roadmap..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your question is a feature request or something where you've already posted a clear position on the issue (*"I think X should happen"*), then it's pointless to reiterate it by adding an answer that agrees with yourself.

If your post is an open-ended question (*"What should we do about X?"*), feel free to add an answer with your stance on the issue so it can be voted on independently of the question.

It's rarely necessary, but sometimes it makes sense. If you have a feature request or proposal, it can be a good idea not to include your specific idea for implementation, as people tend to get pre-occupied with the little details you suggest rather than the big picture.

Go ahead and try it, and let the votes and comments guide you.

Comment: + 1 I think that's a great answer and I totally agree. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if the users that decides the fate of such proposals takes question votes into account when they decide if they should implement something or not? Or do they only look at the answers?

Comment: I can't answer that with total confidence, but I believe that vote counts aren't taken into account that much when deciding to implement feature requests. Lots of highly voted ideas that never happen, several low vote proposals that get handled promptly. If your idea is that the extra votes or agreeing answers will push the request higher up the totem pole, I think the answer is no.

Comment: It's strange, look at [this post of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119333/remove-accept-rate-display-from-questions-move-it-to-the-profile-page). It has a -5 score with 22 downvotes, but the top answer which totally agrees with me has a score of 11 with only one downvote.

Comment: I'm thinking more of proposals where the proposal outscores the top answer by at least 2:1, however the top answer doesn't agree with the question. I think I see your point though. Providing the proposal is clear, you don't need an answer supporting it

Comment: @Rachel Sometimes people vote up proposals on meta to say "Yeah, this is an issue that should be discussed" rather than to endorse a particular position on the matter. That probably happens mostly in the open-ended questions Wesley mentions above, so in that case, yes, submit an answer with a specific opinion on that open-ended issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the users that decide the fate of such proposals take question
>   votes into account when they decide if they should implement something
>   or not? Or do they only look at answers?

There is evidence that downvoted things implemented

- ["Close -- exact duplicate" process is buggy and annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32690/close-exact-duplicate-process-is-buggy-and-annoying)
- ["Full Time Employee versus Contract Work?" on SO should have been migrated to Programmers instead of deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124323/full-time-employee-versus-contract-work-on-so-should-have-been-migrated-to-pr)
- [Please reopen this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131712/please-reopen-this-question)

And heavily upvoted things get declined

- [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)
- [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)
- [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased) (This one has a particularly weird history)

So my guess is that while the community has influence the SE team makes its own judgements and priorities.